# iOS: Constraining View with fixed aspect ratio to trailing edge OR bottom edge

Tags: ios, xcode, user-interface, interface, constraints

I have an ImageView that is constraint to be a square and on its top edge:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/F0Hgx.png

The problem is that I want the view to fill the entire bottom space without exceeding the superview. In other words it should conform to either the width or the remaining height depending on which one is smaller.

The guide I am following suggests to add all of these to a stack view, but  that is an iOS 9 feature and I want to develop for iOS8. What would be a good solution for that SDK?

Comment: There are many ways, One think you can add aspect ratio constraints.  You can add leading and training to super view constraints, set image contentMode to AspectFit. I think this may give you an idea.

Comment: The image view already has aspect ratio constraints of 1:1 which leads to my problem - you do not know if you should constrain it to the trailing edge or to the bottom edge because you do not know which one will be smaller

Comment: I am afraid, there may be better solution. What you can do is create height and width constraints. You can create outlet for that constraints. You can calculate the correct value programmatically. Set it to constraints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would add width = height constraint to keep the aspect ratio, then bottom and trailing constraints with lower priority (900) and >= margin value (ex 8) . This way image will be a square and it will not go over bottom or right. Also aspect fit should be set.